# create one plot with two boxes, each belonging to a different boxplot in r

Tags: r

Can you please help me obtain one boxplot with two boxes, one belonging to females and the other to males,

Here is what I have : . And sorry for not putting the entire code, but it kept giving me an error.

```
m1 <-matrix(sample(x = 1:4, size = 35*15, replace = TRUE), nrow = 35, ncol = 15)

us<-c("CALIFORNIA","FLORIDA","ARIZONA","MICHIGAN","WASHINGTON","GEORGIA","TEXAS","OHIO","ALABAMA","COLORADO","NEW JERSEY","VIRGINIA","MONTANA","OREGON","NEW YORK")

colnames(m1) = us

num<-c(1:35)
rownames (m1) = num

m2<- as.matrix(m1)


females<-m2[1:20,]

males<-m2[21:35,]

f1<-data.frame(females)

boxplot(f1, main = "Carrot Juice Survey - FEMALES ",
           xlab = "STATE",
           ylab = "LEVEL OF SATISFACTION",
           col = "pink",
           border = "brown",
           varwidth=TRUE,
           BOXWEX=0.2)

f2<-data.frame(males)

boxplot(f2, main = "Carrot Juice Survey - MALES",
           xlab = "STATE",
           ylab = "LEVEL OF SATISFACTION",
           col = "blue",
           border = "black",
           varwidth=TRUE,
           BOXWEX=0.2)
```

[image: Boxplot]

Comment: This worked.. thank you, but I had tried that before, and I am getting two identical boxes with the same mean, which is not accurate.  I am attaching a pic above.

Comment: I ran the code a couple more times and now it worked.

Comment: I have a question though, what is the difference between using the list and unlist function, because I used the list function before and it worked: boxplot(list(males,females), main = "Carrot Juice Survey")

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Here is how you can make the attached graph:

```
boxplot(unlist(f1), unlist(f2), main = "Carrot Juice Survey",
        xlab = "STATE",
        ylab = "LEVEL OF SATISFACTION",
        col = "blue",
        border = "black",
        varwidth=TRUE,
        BOXWEX=0.2,
        names = c("males","females"))
```

[image: boxplot]